# Использование метода split() для большого текстового файла

Tags: java, split

У меня есть огромный файл можно сказать книга, и я хочу сделать split чтоб смог посчитать сколько раз каждое слово встречается в файле. Но непонятно как использовать метод `split()`, потому что в тексте огромное количество знаков пробелов. Это не помогает `String[] words = line.split(" ");`

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\customer1.txt"))) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine().toLowerCase(); 
String[] words = line.split(" ");
```

Comment: `Это не помогает` что это значит?

Comment: line.split(" "); не разделяет текст по словам

Comment: [Да ну....](https://ideone.com/PPD7wo)

Comment: Я ведь написал у меня текстовый файл, в котором огромный текст, а в нем разные символы, штук сто, не только пробел, как в этом случае сделать

Comment: в Твоем же примере, есть запитая которая не должна быть

Comment: Речь же шла о пробелах

Comment: ну так сделай что-то более продвинутое чем split. Удали все знаки из строки кроме букв и пробелов с помощью replaceAll и потом сделай split.

Comment: [Много способов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726023/split-string-into-individual-words-java)

Comment: а в чем вопрос-то?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, `String::split` помогает.

Во-вторых, для исключения нескольких пробельных символов, идущих подряд, следует использовать регулярное выражение `.split("\\s+")`, однако оно не исключает знаки пунктуации, которые будут включаться в слова.  Можно применять разбиение по [другим POSIX-классам символов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

- `.split("\\P{L}+")` - разбить по всем символам, *не являющимся* буквами (`\\P` - отрицание)
- `.split("\\P{Alnum}+")` - разбить по всем символам, *не являющимися* буквами или цифрами
- `.split("[\\p{Space}\\p{Punct}]+")` - разбить по всем символам, являющимися пробельными символами или знаками пунктуации

В-третьих, для подсчета частоты слов следует использовать словарь/хэш-таблицу слов `Map<String, Long>`, где слово является ключом, частота -- значением.

Используя NIO API для чтения файлов и Java Stream API, можно написать такую реализацию:

```java
public static Map<String, Long> wordFreqMap(String filename) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
        return input  // Stream<String> - поток строк
            .map(line -> line.split("\\P{Alnum}+"))   // Stream<String[]> - массивы слов
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream) // Stream<String> - поток слов
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                word -> word,          // сгруппировать по ключам-словам
                Collectors.counting()  // подсчитать частоту
            ));
    }
}
```

Операции `.map` + `flatMap` можно объединить в одну, а также проигнорировать регистр букв в словах благодаря использованию `String::toLowerCase` (или `String::toUpperCase`) для приведения к единому регистру

```java
try (Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
    return input // Stream<String> - поток строк
        .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\P{Alnum}+")))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            word -> word.toLowerCase(), // ключ-слово строчными буквами
            Collectors.counting()  // подсчитать частоту
        ));
}
```

Comment: анонимный -1 как награда за улучшение старого ответа..

Answer (score -1):

Я в java не силен, но возможно вы сможете найти ответ на примере Python кода:

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open("text.txt") as file_book:
    for line in file_book:
        words = line
        
word_list = words.split()

word_count_dict = defaultdict(int) 

for word in word_list:
    word_count_dict[word] += 1
    print(word, word_count_dict[word])
```